# oracle db current_date returns java.sql.Timestamp, not java.sql.Date

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timestamp

oracle db JDBC:

```
select current_date from dual
```

It returns a java.sql.Timestamp, not java.sql.Date instance.

```
select current_timestamp from dule
```

It returns a oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ, not java.sql.Timestamp instance.

How to make them return values of JDBC java.sql.* standard types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` data type has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components.

In Java:

- a `java.sql.Date` class has year, month and day components.
- a `java.sql.Timestamp` class has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components.

The correct Java data type for an Oracle `DATE` is `java.sql.Timestamp` and not `java.sql.Date` (you can use `java.sql.Date` as the return value from stored procedures, etc. but it will truncate the time components).

---

In Oracle, [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions037.htm) has the data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In Java, this is the equivalent of `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ` class.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL returns Oracle data types. You can use trunc(current_date) to get rid of the time part (not that it will affect the return type, though!). However, to get the right data type with JDBC, simply use the proper get method in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html. The `getDate` method returns a `java.sql.Date`, the `getTimestamp` method returns a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: getXXX() vs getObject(): When using getXXX(...) methods, resultSet.getInt(index) throws exception if it is null. How to deal with null values?

Comment: You need to check if the result set has any data. example., 
while (resultSet.next()) {  
          System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2));
             
      }

Comment: Actually getInt is documented to return 0 for null values. You can use wasNull to check if it was null or not. If you get a NullPointerException for getInt, post the stack trace.